# Ubuntu doesn't set Permissions(chmod) on NTFS files even after Setting Udev Rule

Tags: udev, chmod, ntfs-3g

I know the fact that `chmod` does not work with NTFS. However, I'm trying to set a permission (say 0755) when I mount an NTFS drive using Nautilus. I've already configured a udev rule for that; I have appended `MODE=0022` to each lines that start with `KERNEL` in `/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules`.

For example:

`KERNEL=="sd*[!0-9]|sr*", ENV{ID_SERIAL}!="?*", SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi", ATTRS{vendor}=="ATA", IMPORT{program}="ata_id --export $devnode", MODE="0022"`

I click on the drive name that appears on left pane of Nautilus to mount the drive as shown in the image below:

[image]

Now, when I create a file on that drive, the permission defaults to 777. And, `chmod` does not change the permission.

[image]

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and the Kernel version is 4.4.0-24-generic.

Comment: how did you make that little animation? it's slick

Comment: Using ffmpeg and imagemagick.

Comment: Is this a hot-swappable USB drive ? If so you may want to actually _mount_ yr drive (from a udev rule) with the proper mount options. Let me know using @Cbhihe in yr reply.

Comment: @Cbhihe This is not a USB drive.  It's an internal hard drive. I want to mount internal drive when I click its name on the left pane of Nautilus.

Comment: From what I remember, and this is very tentative, on one hand, Nautilus mounts volumes via `udisksctl`, the `udisks` cli-tool. On the other hand, if I am not mistaken udev rules were planned for hot-plug devices only (hence my confusion earlier). So for yr internal drive, inserting an `fstab` entry with the `noauto` option will prevent it from being mounted automatically at boot or via `$ mount -a` in terminal.  Yr `fstab` should also arrange for mounting yr NTFS drive with the required options. Did you try that + checked access permissions after dble-clicking left-pane entry in Nautilus ?

Comment: @Cbhihe Thank you so much! It worked like a charm. Appreciated!

Comment: I will write an answer for other users. If it suits you, check it as accepted so others with the same need may take note of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On one hand I believe that Nautilus mounts volumes via `udisksctl`, the udisks cli-tool.

On the other hand, if I am not mistaken `udev` rules were planned for hot-plug devices only. So if yr volume to be mounted is an ***internal drive***, inserting an `fstab` entry with the `noauto` option will prevent it from being mounted automatically at boot or via `$ mount -a` in terminal.

Yr `/etc/fstab` should also arrange for mounting yr NTFS drive with the required options. An example of that along the line of yr post could be:

```
UUID=30683E97683E5C32   /mnt/ntfs-vol1 ntfs-3g rw,user,noauto,relatime,umask=0002,x-gvfs-show,utf8,x-gvfs-name=ntfs-vol1 0 2
```

Change the above to reflect yr volume's UUID, yr mount-point, "/mnt/ntfs-vol1",  and the volume label, "ntfs-vol1". Other options are available.